# How to send Travis output to GitHub

Tags: github, travis-ci, github-api

I'm trying to fix up a broken Travis CI build script on a repo I was added to as a contributor.  Everything works fine in the actual build, but trying to upload the build results to GitHub is broken.

The `.travis.yml` file contains an OAuth token which it puts into the Environment, and at the end it runs a script that retrieves this environment variable and uses it to upload the build output to GitHub.  This is failing with a `401 Unauthorized` error, which means the token is probably no longer valid.

I didn't write this up, and the way this works kind of bugs me.  I'm not comfortable having authentication information in the repo, publicly accessible to the world, so it's just as well that this token is expired.  But as I look things over, I don't see any better way to do this.

I need to do one of two things, either have the Travis build machine upload the build result to GitHub, or download the build result from Travis and upload it myself.  Unfortunately, neither one seems to be a good option.  No matter where I look on Travis CI's Web interface, I can't find any download link to retrieve the build results, which seems to rule out the second option.  As for the first option, it doesn't appear that there's any way to perform the upload without the build machine having authentication information from the repository.

I can't be the first person to notice how problematic this is.  I figure it has to be solved somehow; I'm just not sure how to fix it.  Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Comment: Would encrypting it be suitable https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/environment-variables/#Defining-encrypted-variables-in-.travis.yml

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "trying to upload the build results to GitHub"? If you just want the pass/fail/error result, you can see those in the "history" (e.g., https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-build/commits). If you just want the logs, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48585545/travis-ci-job-logs-to-text-file#comment84205725_48585545.

Comment: @banzaiman I mean the binaries that result from a successful build.